# Is there a way to skip the level before the final bossfight?

Tags: serious-sam-3-bfe

I'm playing through Serious Sam 3 in Coop and we failed at what I presume is the final boss ( Ugh-Zan IV I think he is called. He regenerates health, you get a jet pack for the first time).

Unfortunately we failed and the only way to try again we found is to restart the entire map. However that map is quite long and tedious, is there a way to skip directly to the boss?

Comment: Why would you have to restart the map to try again? Unless you have a limited number of lives, you should simply respawn. If your lives are limited, you should automatically reload your last save. In any case, unless you have a savegame from right before the boss, no, you cannot skip directly to the last boss. Turn on autosave in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There was a way, but Croteam fixed that bug: [Guardian of Time in 5 min](https://youtu.be/NHUextvifTQ?t=25s)

Some players can still skip half the map when you fight Technopolips (in the area at 2:30 in video), by luring the sandworm to the wrong position where it can't kill you, but I think it is too hard and best just to use that time to try again.